# MarkLogic POJO Data Binding Interface: JSONMappingException when performing a POJO search

Tags: java, marklogic, pojo

I'm working with the MarkLogic POJO Databinding Interface at the moment. I'm able to write POJOs to MarkLogic. Now I want to search those POJOs and retrieve the search results. I'm following the instructions from: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/binding#id_89573 However, the search results don't seem to return the correct objects. I'm getting a JSONMappingException. Here's the code:

```
    HashMap<String, MatchedPropertyInfo> matchedProperties = new HashMap<String, MatchedPropertyInfo>();
    PropertyMatches PM = new PropertyMatches(123,"uri/prefix/location2", "uri/prefix", 1234,0,"/aKey","/aLocation",true,matchedProperties);
    MatchedPropertyInfo MPI1 = new MatchedPropertyInfo("matched/property/uri1", "matched/property/key1", "matched/property/location1", true,"ValueMatch1", 12, 1*1.0/3, true);
    MatchedPropertyInfo MPI2 = new MatchedPropertyInfo("matched/property/uri2", "matched/property/key2", "matched/property/location2", true,"ValueMatch2", 14, 1.0/2.0, true);
    PM.getMatchedProperties().put("matched/property/prefix/location1", MPI1);
    PM.getMatchedProperties().put("matched/property/prefix/location2", MPI2);

    PojoRepository myClassRepo = client.newPojoRepository(PropertyMatches.class, Long.class);
    myClassRepo.write(PM);

    PojoQueryBuilder qb = myClassRepo.getQueryBuilder();
    PojoPage<PropertyMatches> matches = myClassRepo.search(qb.value("uri", "uri/prefix/location2"),1);
    if (matches.hasContent()) {
        while (matches.hasNext()) {
            PropertyMatches aPM = matches.next();
            System.out.println("  " + aPM.getURI());
        }
     } else {
        System.out.println("  No matches");
     }
```

The PropertyMatches (PM) object is succesfully written to the MarkLogic database. This class contains a member: `private String URI` which is initiated with `"uri/prefix/location2"`. The `matches.hasContent()` returns true in the example above. However, I'm getting an error on `PropertyMatches aPM = matches.next();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching POJOs in MarkLogic and read them into your Java program requires the POJOs to have an empty constructor. In this case `PropertyMatches` should have `public PropertyMatches(){}` and MatchedPropertyInfo should have `public MatchedPropertyInfo(){}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sjoerd999 for posting the answer you found.  Just to add some documentation references, this topic is discussed here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/binding#id_54408 and here: https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/pojo/PojoRepository.html.

Also worth noting is you can have multiple parameters in the consructor, you just have to do it the Jackson way.  Here are examples of two ways (with annotations and without): https://manosnikolaidis.wordpress.com/2015/08/25/jackson-without-annotations/

I'd recommend using annotations as that's built-in with Jackson.  But if you want to do it without annotations, here's the code:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Avoid having to annotate the Person class
    // Requires Java 8, pass -parameters to javac
    // and jackson-module-parameter-names as a dependency
    mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());

    // make private fields of Person visible to Jackson
    mapper.setVisibility(FIELD, ANY);
```

If you want to do this with PojoRepository you'll have to use the unsupported getObjectMapper method to get the ObjectMapper and call registerModule and setVisibility on that:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = ((PojoRepositoryImpl) myClassRepo).getObjectMapper();
```